# how to reload getx controller?

Tags: android, flutter, controller, flutter-getx

hi I try using Getx Controller in flutter. I want my oninit of controller reload and set the new data each time user go two my certain page, but only the first time page reload oninint excute. how can I set onInit reload each time user go to this page?

```
my onInit code is:
```

```
@override
Future<void> onInit() async {
  super.onInit();
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  name = (sharedPreferences.getString('name') ?? '-1').obs;
  avatarImage = (sharedPreferences.getString('imageAddress') ?? '-1').obs;
  username = sharedPreferences.getString('username') ?? '-1';
  file = File(avatarImage.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the controllers aren't named, I will say that we have a `ReloadedController` which contains the `onInit()` in your code snippet, and we have the `SpecificPageController` that belongs to that specific page.

I can think of two solutions that will suit your case:

**First sulution**: delete the controller and inject it again, to execute the `onInit()`:

```
class SpecificPageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    Get.delete<ReloadedController>();
    Get.put(ReloadedController());
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

This will delete the `ReloadedController` from the memory, then inject it again, this will trigger the `OnInit()` to execute since we just injected it.

**Second solution**: forcefully execute the `onInit()` method:

```
class SpecificPageController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    Get.find<ReloadedController>().onInit();
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

This will execute forcefully the `OnInit()` method, which will behave like a reload for your `onInit()` code every time the specific page will be opened.

**Third, solution**: using `onGenerateRoute`

```
return GetMaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    if (settings.name == "/yourSpecificPageRoure") {
      name = (sharedPreferences.getString('name') ?? '-1').obs;
      avatarImage =
          (sharedPreferences.getString('imageAddress') ?? '-1').obs;
      username = sharedPreferences.getString('username') ?? '-1';
      file = File(avatarImage.value);
    }
  },
// ...
```

Change `/yourSpecificPageRoure` with your route path name.

This method is called every time a route is generated in your app, the price of your code will be executed only when the route name is `/yourSpecificPageRoure`.

Comment: thank you for your answer it is work now. and I find forth solution. we can use the lazyPut  too. so each to the page controller delete from memory and when back to that page create again, for example: Get.lazyPut<HomeScreenController>(() => HomeScreenController(),fenix: true);